# plotting a list of strings in matplotlib

Tags: string, list, matplotlib

I have a a big file (called Data) that is a list of strings, its 175693 lines but i only want to work with lines 8 to 151799. An abbreviated version of the file follows:

```
Name                 Group          Measured         Modelled         Residual         Weight
 pdwl1                pdwls          2083.620         2089.673        -6.052805        9.4067000E-04
 pdwl2                pdwls          2186.748         2199.771        -13.02284        8.9630800E-04
 pdwl3                pdwls          2150.983         2160.259        -9.275730        9.1121100E-04
 pdwl4                pdwls          2133.283         2142.970        -9.686504        9.1877100E-04
 pdwl5                pdwls          2241.741         1769.331         472.4097        8.7432100E-04
 pst_1                devwls         2191.200         2094.658         96.54200         1.000000    
 pst_2                devwls         2194.160         2094.070         100.0900         1.000000    
 pst_3                devwls         2190.790         2093.375         97.41500         1.000000    
 pst_4                devwls         2191.700         2092.671         99.02900         1.000000    
 pst_5                devwls         2188.260         2092.739         95.52100         1.000000   
 devfl1               devflux       1.2788475E+07    1.2199410E+07     589064.6        1.4030900E-06
 devfl2               devflux       1.2208086E+07    1.2044727E+07     163359.4        1.4030900E-06
 devfl3               devflux       1.3559062E+07    1.1423958E+07     2135104.        1.4030900E-06
 devfl4               devflux       1.2419465E+07    1.1141419E+07     1278046.        1.4030900E-06
 devfl5               devflux       1.2070242E+07    1.0925833E+07     1144409.        1.4030900E-06
```

I need to plot measured values versus modelled values,  I want one plot for measured v modeled for Group==pdwls, another plot for measured v residual for Group==pdwls, then for meas v modeled fro Group == devwls and a plot for meas v residual for devwls

Here is what i have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('elm3_1-4 - Copy.rei', dtype=None, names=True)
#data = np.genfromtxt('elm3_1-4-pdwls.rei', dtype=None, names=True)
#data = np.genfromtxt('elm3_1-4-devwls.rei', dtype=None, names=True)

for data[6:1643] in data:
    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.scatter(data['Measured'], data['Modelled'])
    plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)')
    plt.ylabel('Modelled (ft)')
    plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Pre-Development WLs') 
    plt.xlim(1000,4000)
    plt.ylim(-2000,4000)
    plt.scatter(data['Measured'], data['Residual'])
    plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)')
    plt.ylabel('Residual (Meas - Model) (ft)')
    plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Pre-Development: Measured WLs v Resduals') 
    plt.xlim(1000,4000)
    plt.ylim(-1000,1000)
    plt.subplot(2,2,2)
    plt.show()
for data[1644:151798] in data:
    plt.subplot(2,2,3)
    plt.scatter(data['Measured'], data['Modelled'])
    plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)')
    plt.ylabel('Modelled (ft)')
    plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Development WLs') 
    plt.xlim(1000,4000)
    plt.ylim(1000,4000)
    plt.scatter(data['Measured'], data['Residual'])
    plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)')
    plt.ylabel('Residual (Meas - Model) (ft)')
    plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Development: Measured WLs v Resduals') 
    plt.xlim(1000,4000)
    plt.ylim(-1000,1000)
    plt.subplot(2,2,4)
    plt.show()
```

The code runs but it generates no plots. All i get in the command window is:

```
Line #175688 (got 6 columns instead of 9).
```

There are multiple lines involved in the message, not just 175688.
I edited this question to with the for loops entered in for the new example dataset.

Thanks

Comment: If you just want to plot `data` for the points between `1644` and `151798`, don't use a `for` loop, just plot `data[1644:151798]` instead of `data`, e.g.: `plt.scatter(data[1644:151798]['Measured'], data[1644:151798]['Modelled'])`

Comment: Ok, i tried this plt.scatter(data[7:1643]['Measured'], data[7:1643]['Modelled']) but i still get the message Line #175685 (got 6 columns instead of 9) and also when i try to print data it says NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: Oh, that error probably comes from the first line with `np.genfromtxt`, not your plotting.  It seems that line 175685 in your file has 6 values instead of 9.  You'll have to look at your input file.

Comment: im not sure why it says 6 instead of 9. The dataset has 6 columns all the way down. There never should be 9, nor is there 9 columns anywhere in the dataset.

Comment: Oh I see, very strange, I had those numbers switched in my head but now I see your example starts with 6, not 9.  I can't reproduce the problem, as when I copy your data to a file, I get 6 values all the way down, as expected.  What does line `175684` (just above the problem) look like?

Comment: I think i know the problem, there is a header on my data set with 9 seperate strings. I think genfromtxt is taking its intial formatting from that.

Comment: You can use `skip_header=1` to skip the first line, but then you cannot use `names=True` to grab the names from the header.  You could also try, `np.genfromtxt(..., dtype=None, names=True, usecols=range(6))` to explicitly use only the first six columns.

Comment: I used skip_header=6 because there are 6 lines before i get to the headers i want to use. I looks like it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data file actually looks like that, then you can use:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('elm3_1-4 - Copy.rei', dtype=None, names=True)
```

And `dtype=None` means it will automatically determine the best type for each column, and `names=True` means it'll create a structured array with fields with names from the first line in your file.  Yours will look like this:

```
array([('pdwl1', 'pdwls', 2083.62, 2089.673, -6.052805, 0.00094067),
       ('pdwl2', 'pdwls', 2186.748, 2199.771, -13.02284, 0.000896308),
       ('pdwl3', 'pdwls', 2150.983, 2160.259, -9.27573, 0.000911211),
       ('pdwl4', 'pdwls', 2133.283, 2142.97, -9.686504, 0.000918771)], 
      dtype=[('Name', 'S5'), ('Group', 'S5'), ('Measured', '<f8'), ('Modelled', '<f8'), ('Residual', '<f8'), ('Weight', '<f8')])
```

To plot, e.g., `'Measured'` vs. `'Modelled'`, use:

```
plt.plot(data['Modelled'], data['Measured'])
```

[image: MvM]

To be clear, everything you've posted above can be reduced to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('elm3_1-4 - Copy.rei', dtype=None, names=True)

plt.plot(data['Modelled'], data['Measured'])
plt.ylabel('Measured')
plt.xlabel('Modelled')
plt.title('Title')                 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do i add the genfromtxt to the existing code or does it negate the use of all the loops and if statements? Im not sure how to integrate your suggestion into my code. Also, the data file is much bigger, many mroe lines, thats just a snipit

Comment: It replaces all of your file-loading lines :)  Your data filesize shouldn't matter.  I've edited my answer to show the full thing.

Comment: I edited the original question, with a new script with some loops. If anyone has advice i'd appreciate it

Comment: In general on stack overflow, you should post a new separate question for such a big edit.  You'll get more attention, and the post and answers will make more sense to future visitors.  As it stands, my answer makes no sense with respect to the new question, since it solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code gets what i want

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('elm3_1-4 - Copy.rei', dtype=None, names=True, skip_header=6)

font = {'size'   : 10,}

#-----PreDevelopment plots__________________________________
plt.rc('axes', color_cycle=['r'])
plt.subplot(2,3,1)
plt.scatter(data[7:1643]['Measured'], data[7:1643]['Modelled'])
plt.plot([0,4000],[0,4000])
plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Modelled (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Pre-Development WLs', fontdict=font) 
plt.xlim(1000,4000)
plt.ylim(-2000,4000)

plt.rc('axes', color_cycle=['r'])
plt.subplot(2,3,2)
plt.scatter(data[7:1643]['Measured'], data[7:1643]['Residual'])
plt.plot([0,4000],[4000,4000])
plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Residual (Meas - Model) (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Pre-Development: \n Measured WLs v Residual', fontdict=font) 
plt.xlim(1000,4000)
plt.ylim(-1000,1000)
plt.show()

plt.rc('axes', color_cycle=['r'])
plt.subplot(2,3,3)
plt.scatter(data[151761:151798]['Measured'], data[151761:151798]['Modelled'])
plt.plot([0,4000],[0,4000])
plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Modelled (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Pre-Development \n Measured BFs v Modelled BFs', fontdict=font) 
#plt.xlim(1000,4000)
#plt.ylim(-2000,4000)
plt.show()

#-----Development plots__________________________________
plt.subplot(2,3,4)
plt.scatter(data[1644:151760]['Measured'], data[1644:151760]['Modelled'])
plt.plot([0,4000],[0,4000])
plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Modelled (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Development WLs', fontdict=font) 
plt.xlim(1000,4000)
plt.ylim(1000,4000)

plt.subplot(2,3,5)
plt.scatter(data[1644:151760]['Measured'], data[1644:151760]['Residual'])
plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Residual (Meas - Model) (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Development: \n Measured WLs v Resduals', fontdict=font)
plt.plot([0,4000],[4000,4000])
plt.xlim(1000,4000)
plt.ylim(-1000,1000)
plt.show() 
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)

plt.subplot(2,3,6)
plt.scatter(data[151799:175132]['Measured'], data[151799:175132]['Residual'])
plt.xlabel('Measured (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Residual (Meas - Model) (ft)', fontdict=font)
plt.title('ELM3_1-4 Development: \n Measured BFs v Modelled BFs', fontdict=font)
plt.plot([0,4000],[4000,4000])
#plt.xlim(1000,4000)
#plt.ylim(-1000,1000)
plt.show() 
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
```